# How to run a batch process in regular interval

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I need  to Unpublish the nodes which are all not Updated for more than some specified time.

I'm having the query to fetch nodes and by using a batch process I will Unpublish those nodes one by one.

Now I want to schedule this operation to be run every day. How can I achieve that? using drush or something.

I have cron running at regular intervals. I need to run these scripts apart from the cron job i.e as a separate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can achieve it by using a Cron job and Batch/Queue as mentioned by Anoop Joseph with some changes

**Method I - Using Cron and queue**

- Cron will run the query and push the list of nodes to the queue
- queue will pick the items one by one and Unpublish them

**Method - II Using Cron and batch**

- Cron will run the query and push the list of nodes to the Batch process
- Batch process will be launched programmatically using [background_process](http://drupal.org/project/background_process) module

In both methods Cron can be configured in such way that It runs the query once for every day by storing the last run time in a variable

Answer (score 4):

You can use cron to do this, set a cron time in admin/config/system/cron for your site.

there is a hook_cron() is available in your drupal . using that hook you can configure your batch process to invoke.

Comment: Cron is already running at regular intervals. I want to run this one apart from cron. Will update the question also.

Comment: To schedule your task to run at particular intervals cron is the correct one. you can use http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron to get a fine grain control over each task. You can do your particular batch operation alone. why you are trying to run these scripts apart from the cron job?

Comment: But un-publishing 10K nodes using node_save in cron will not be good :)

Comment: i mean use hook_cron to invoke your batch process

Comment: you can write your batch process function in a menu call back, and add the particular path in cron job with help of elysya cron

Comment: Found out the solution. Its possible with cron as you mentioned with some changes. Added my answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

The batch api is primary design to work with forms and it depends what is the purpose of your use, but you can create a function that mimic form submission, and then you can use batch together with cron, assume you have function that will be triggered by a rule on cron run, so this function is function1:

```
<?php
function function1 () {
    $form_state = array();
    $form_state['values']['hidden_value'] = 1;
    $form_state['values']['op'] = 'Test';
    $form_state['values']['submit'] = 'Test';
    drupal_form_submit('function1_batch_form',
    $form_state);
} 
function function1_batch_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['hidden_value'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => 1,
  );
  return $form;
}
function function1_batch_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['hidden_value'] == 1) {
    $batch = function1_batch_process($date);
    batch_set($batch);
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but if you really need things running at different times I might tackle it like this:

Start by setting up a rule with a custom rules action. You can use any logic you want here (because it's in a module using hook_action), I would check for a cache of nodes and process up-to X number of them if a cache is found or create a new cache and process up to X number of them if there is no cache.

The next part would be to set up the rule to happen on a specific page load and request that page with cron at whatever interval you want.